# CMake script can't start android emulator

Tags: android, cmake, dcmtk

I'm trying to build the DCMTK Dicom Toolkit for the Android OS. The toolkit is written in C and C++. They provide CMake files and reading their documentation using Android Cmake and android.toolchain.cmake I should be able to build library for Android usage. Following the instructions I stop at the following line:

```
IF(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM MATCHES "Windows.*")
  SET(COMMAND sh -c " ${ANDROID_EMULATOR_PROGRAM} -avd ${ANDROID_EMULATOR_AVD} 
-no-boot-anim -noaudio -prop emu.uuid=${EMULATOR_UUID} >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &")

EXECUTE_PROCESS(
  COMMAND ${COMMAND}
  RESULT_VARIABLE RESULT
  OUTPUT_QUIET
  ERROR_QUIET
)
```

The android emulator can not be started. I have created an android emulator and I can start it from the console. The value of ${COMMAND} is:

> -- sh-c C:/Program Files (x86)/android-sdk/tools/emulator.exe -avd androidDevice  -no-boot-anim -noaudio -prop
>   emu.uuid=1f7524708f34a3d82286b2862c8eab66 >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null
>   &

The name of the emulator I created is androidDevice and I guess the uuid is also correctly retrieved at the previous steps. I have no experience with CMake, is this a valid command and where could be the error?

Comment: What if you remove the redirection to /dev/null to see that are the errors ?

Comment: You're creating the command only IF(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM MATCHES "Windows.*"). Could that be right? I would recommend putting message("CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM: ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM}") before that if, just to be sure what values you're dealing with. Plus, do what Gerald said.

Comment: Probably sh is not in the path? It is a common tool on Unices, but for Windows I would expect cmd.exe or maybe sh.exe

Comment: I saw that sh is not recognized in cmd, so I added its path to my environment variables. There was another problem also: ${ANDROID_EMULATOR_PROGRAM} variable contains the global path to emulator.exe, but it resides inside Program Files x(86) (the path contains spaces). I tried fixing it with quotes, it didn't work, don't know why, and at the end I added the path to emulator.exe in environment variables. I changed the value of ${ANDROID_EMULATOR_PROGRAM} to emulator.exe and it worked. Thank you guys!